# Using two checks in elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to fetch data from an elasticsearch index when the following criteria are met.

1. When the `stream_id` is an empty string (e.g. "")
2. When the `source_id` is a specific string (e.g. "unknown_source")

I can use the two following queries separately:
For checking empty string:

```
{
"query": {
  "filtered": {
    "filter": {
      "script": {
        "script": "_source.stream_id.length() == 0"
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

For checking `source_id`

```
{
"query": { 
  "bool" : {
    "must" : {
      "term" : { "source_id" : "unknown_source" }
    }
  }
}
}
```

But now I see the 'filtered' query is deprecated in ES version 2.0 and I'm using version 2.1. So, how do I AND these two conditions? I've looked into the filtered query page documentation and it says

> Use the bool query instead with a must clause for the query and a filter 
>   clause for the filter.

So, then I was trying the following query but it's not working.

```
{
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must" : {
        "term" : { "source_id" : "unknown_source" }
    },
    "filter": {
        "script": {
            "script": "_source.stream_id.length() == 0"
        }
    }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this with a `bool/must` inside the `filter` section (since you don't care about the scoring)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "script": {
                "script": "_source.stream_id.length() == 0"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "source_id": "unknown_source"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or you can also spare two levels and have it all in the query context (even though you don't care about the scoring)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": "_source.stream_id.length() == 0"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "source_id": "unknown_source"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The 1st code gets an error saying 'QueryParsingException[[apache_combined] [bool] query does not support [filter]]'. Also, I need both of these conditions to match.

Comment: My uri is  'http://localhost:9200/apache_combined/_search?fields=message'. The 2nd query throws an error saying 'QueryParsingException[[apache_combined] No query registered for [script]]; }]",' I've added the 'script.disable_dynamic: false' entry in elasticsearch.yml

Comment: I've updated my answer, i.e. `must` instead of `should`, sorry about that. In 2.1 you need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) with `script.inline: on`

Comment: Sorry, but even after enabling dynamic scripting I'm getting parsing failure `No query registered for [script]`

Comment: Even for the first query? And you're on 2.1?

Comment: For the 1st query I'm getting `nested: QueryParsingException[[ca_combined] [bool] query does not support [filter]` and oh crap, I thought I was using 2.1 but I'm using 1.7.1.

Comment: Ah!! There you go, that's why then. So if you need a 1.7.1 compliant query, the second one should do, but I advise you to do it in a filtered query.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've moved to es 2.1 and it's working fine.

Comment: Awesome, glad to help!